# Unity Event System with Scriptable Objects: how to completely avoid using a singleton

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a scriptable object which I instantiate from a MonoBehaviour. I'm able to communicate back and forth between both and raise events accordingly. But there are more MonoBehaviours in my scene that need to do some other back and forth stuff with the scriptable object too. And the scriptable object "belongs" to that specific MonoBehaviour where it was instantiated.

So my question is: how can I access the scriptable object instantiated by "MonoBehaviour A" from "MonoBehaviour B", "MonoBehaviour C", "MonoBehaviour D", etc?

Right now I'm making "Monobehaviour A" a singleton, so it is accessible to the other MonoBehaviours in the scene.

Comment: And is `someGameObject.GetComponent<MonoBehaviourA>()` insufficient?

Comment: @Draco18s Sorry for the confusion: the MonoBehaviours are located in different objects.

Comment: Yes, that's what the `someGameObject` reference is. You can acquire these references by using `GameObject.Find()`, among other ways.

Comment: If you know the objects will be there ahead of time, you can make public fields for the objects you want to communicate with and wire them up using the inspector.

Comment: draco is saying in `MonoBehaviour B` you can get the game object `MonoBehaviourA` is attached to, then grab the script as a `component` then you can modify its variable and use its methods from the calling behaviour as long as there public, it would look like `MonoBehaviourA.scriptableobject.Method()` or `MonoBehaviourA.scriptableobject.variable`

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Resources.FindObjectsOfTypeAll`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.FindObjectsOfTypeAll.html) in order to find all instances of a `ScriptableObject` of certain type.

If there is only one (what I assume since you are using a singleton) in your MonoBehaviours you could use

```c#
var scriptableObject = Resources.FindObjectsOfTypeAll(typeof(YOUR_SCRIPTABLE_CLASS))[0];
```